# calling a new rails page from jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a better way to call a new page in a rails project from a jquery file.
Example:

```
$(function(){

    var products = $('.item');
    products.click(function(event){
        window.location.href = '/products/cans';
        event.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

First off is the above the best approach.
Second is there a way for me not to hard code the url. Instead pass it the route path somehow. "work_cans_path"

Comment: Possibly looking for ajax functionality. I think.

Comment: Ajax wont call a reload of a new page on the window.

Comment: Looks ok to me. This assumes you don't want to load partial data into a div asynchronously in the page. Note you can use something like `window.location.href = '<%= url_for :controller => "products", :action => "cans" %>'` if the jquery file is a js.erb file.